# Aptitude On Kali Linux

Tags: linux, kali-linux, aptitude

I have just installed Kali Linux 2018.2 and tried to search some installed packages on it as i do on Ubuntu

```
aptitude search *package name*
```

but it seems like this command does not work on Kali Linux.

I have also tried to install Aptitude

`/bin/sh -c 'apt-get install -y aptitude'`

but with no success :

```
E: Package 'aptitude' has no installation candidate
```

if Aptitude does not exist on Kali Linux, is there any other alternatives to search the installed packages and the packages that the Kali Linux repositories have?

Output of `cat /etc/*-release`

```
DISTRIB_ID=Kali
DISTRIB_RELEASE=kali-rolling
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Kali GNU/Linux Rolling"
VERSION="2018.2"
ID_LIKE=debian
```

Comment: What debian version are 18.2? That's can be a Ubuntu version but not a debian one. Maybe you're using a derivated distribution who doesn't have aptitude. Also, aptitude is only a "friendly" interface for apt-get

Comment: @SakuraKinomoto i meant 2018.2 
no it's Debian i am sure

Comment: Can you do a "cat /etc/os-release" or "lsb_release -da" and update your question with the result?

Comment: @SakuraKinomoto just did

Comment: That's explain it, it's Kali linux, not Debian.

Comment: @SakuraKinomoto does this change anything ?

Comment: While i'm sure aptitude is on any debian repository, i cannot assure you this on another distro derivated from debian. This change who any expert on Kali linux distro can help you better than me for obtain aptitude on them. But these information not change my answer. You have on my answer a workaround method for all option you can find on aptitude, or at least the more usual ones.

Answer (score 2):

As a first response, maybe you didn't have any repository configured. In this case, apt-get will not work at all. You need to add the repositories for your distribution on /etc/apt/sources.list file. The needed repository are:

> deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib

(You can check a list of mirrors here: http://http.kali.org/README.mirrorlist). Use the best mirror for you.

I don't know how kali linux manages this, but, I can give some guidelines for using directly apt for do who you request:

First of all, remember to do a update for getting the latest packages database:

> apt-get update

For updating all packages:

> apt-get upgrade
>
> apt-get dist-upgrade <-- If you update to a newer release.

For doing searches, use apt too. You can use it too for viewing a concrete package information.

> apt-cache search *package name*
>
> apt-cache show *package name*

For checking if you have a package installed, use dpkg. If the package you're searching for appears on the list (with status / first column as ii) you have it installed:

> dpkg -l | grep *package name*

Also, for added information:

> You can use dpkg for search who package owns a file: dpkg -S *filename*
>
> You can use dpkg for list files from a package: dpkg -L *package*